# Absolute values (URLs) from a list of URLs

Tags: python-3.x

I have a good web scraper that gets me all the html links on the page.  However, I do not need the extra links (relative), just the absolute values.  I have tried two separate ways:

```
link_set = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
    web_links = urljoin(page, link.attrs['href'])     #page is defined URL
    print(web_links)
    link_set.add(web_links)
```

and

```
link_set = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
    web_links = link.get("href")
    print(web_links)
    print(urljoin(page, link['href']))
    link_set.add(web_links)
```

I get the error "TypeError: cannot mix str and non-str arguments.  Am I putting the urljoin in the wrong place?

Comment: Could you give input and desired output?

Comment: Let me give some more code for you.  I give the input of the website defined by page.       page = requests.get('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html')       I use BeautifulSoup to parse the html and the code above to extract all the URLs.  I have a csv writer that writes all the URLs to a file, but in the file i get https:// links and some relative links  (e.g. /survey/2016-estimate.html).   I need an output of only absolute links and not relative links.    I have researched that the function I want/need is urljoin(), but it seems I'm using it improperly.   I hope that helps.